# How to conduct subgroup analysis for multilevel meta-analysis model?

Tags: interaction, multilevel-analysis, metafor

I would like to compare meta-analytic estimates from 2 subgroups using the metafor package. I came across this helpful [guide](http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:comp_two_independent_estimates), but I am using multi-level models (for multiple effect sizes within studies) and the example is not for multi-level models.

The reason I thought this may be a problem is because the example for "Separate meta-analyses" uses tau2 as a measure of heterogeneity in each separate meta-analysis model, but that is not reported in multi-level random-effects meta-analysis models (instead, sigma2 is used).

To make this applicable for multilevel models,

- should I extract sigma2 instead of tau2?
- If so, should this be the sum of sigma2 across all levels or the sigma2 for each level (i.e., 3 estimates in a 3 level model).
- Or does it not matter because tau2 is not used in the comparison of the two estimates (i.e., to obtain Q_moderator and the p-value)?

Comment: The principle that is explained at that link applies all the same, whether you fit multilevel models within subgroups or not. Just collect the pooled effects and corresponding standard errors and test them against each other as described.

Comment: That's great, thank you @Wolfgang!